# Express not loading module if it is unused in another module

Tags: express, module, model

I had a problem with the "require" function for loading modules in express. For example I have this route for "users":

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Activity = require('../models/activity');

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
// other routes handlers
```

In this route I don't use the "Activity" model, and this was the cause of the problem. 
In a schema definition file I had:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Activity = require('./activity');

var daySchema = new Schema({
    // schema definiton
})

daySchema .pre('remove', function(next) {
    Activity.find({
        // here I use the activity Model
    });
module.exports = daySchema;
```

Here the "Activity" model is an empty object whenever I left the unused model in the "users" route. If I remove the "var Activity = require('../models/activity')" from the user model, then it all works fine. Can someone explain why is this happening. It shouldn't be a problem if I left it unused, but apparently this causes a problem loading the model in other modules.

Comment: No such thing. Require simply runs the called module and returns an empty object only if the .exports of the module you're calling returns an empty object. Looks like you're understanding something wrong and asking a question about it. Don't expect anyone to answer this any time soon.

Comment: The model is well defined, the export does not return an empty object. As I mentioned, it works fine if I remove the unused require. Which means, and I tested, that the exports is not empty.

Comment: In that case Activity would not be an empty object. What i'm saying is that there's something you're misunderstanding and nobody can tell what, because you're asking a question based on that wrong assumption. Can't tell why in that case you require is empty cause i don't know your project or your project structure. I was just stating how require works and you should probably read more about it http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/